# Is Qt QML installed by vcpkg?

Tags: macos, qt, qt5, qt-creator, vcpkg

I installed Qt via Vcpkg on macOS. Then I pointed QtCreator to that installation, going on:

```
Preferences
Kits
Qt Versions
```

Then, on right side click Add and choose qmake executable.

But there I see `No QML utility installed`.

I'm aware not everything can be installed by vcpkg (i.e. QtCretor) and I'm wondering if QML can/is actually installed by vcpkg?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

QML stuff is typically in qt5-declarative. You might additional also need qt5-tools. Be aware that if QtCreator is expecting a certain layout of the qml files it might still not work.